# How to find next event based on input value from a listed events?

Tags: java

I have a list of events which should fire based on input given. My event list is:

```
Event1=>8
Event2=>16
Event3=>64
```

Example events:

```
If input is 8 Then Event1 
If input is 16 Then Event2
If input is 24 Then Event1
If input is 32 Then Event2
If input is 40 Then Event1
If input is 48 Then Event2
If input is 56 Then Event1
If input is 64 Then Event3
```

My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = 24;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(8);
    list.add(16);
    list.add(64);
    int i = getEventType(input, list);
}

public static int getOutageType(int input, List<Integer> in) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int event = input;

    for (int v : in) {
        final int diff = Math.abs(v - input);
        if (diff < min) {
            min = diff;
            event = v;
        }
    }

    return event;
}
```

This fails when the input is 24. Expected event is Event1 of 8, but getting Event2 of 16.

Comment: Use an HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>(); Iterate over your events and add them: map.put(input,event); Then retrieve them for a specific input:  return map.get(input);

Comment: @DAO Events may vary and Inputs will also be differ accordingly. Hence I cant map events with inputs in Map.

Comment: Please define *"the next event"*. Right now your `getOutageType` method searches for the value closest to the input, which is `16`, not `8`. Also according to that definition of *"the next event"* the examples should be:  8 -> Event1; 16 -> Event2; 24 -> Event2; 32 -> Event2; 40 -> Event2; 48 -> Event3; 56 -> Event3; 64 -> Event3. Also post your `getEventType` method.